# autocomplete in plain JS from obj data

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I am trying to create an 'autocomplete' search input field in vanilla javascript (no jquery or jquery-ui). I would like the 'autocomplete' to pull from my javascript object data for the 'suggestions'. I am attempting with the below; with no avail (no errors, just no response output). The functionality should be a 'match' narrowing; i.e. I begin typing 's' 's results' will be recommended first, etc.

```js
function matchIt(input) {
  var reg = new RegExp(input.split('').join('\\w*').replace(/\W/, ""), 'i');
  return json.filter(function(file) {
    if (file.match(reg)) {
      return file;
    }
  });
}

function changeInput(val) {
  var autoCompleteResult = matchIt(val);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = autoCompleteResult;
}


var json = [{
  "Name": "zips",
  "Type": "Directory",
  "DateModified": "6/14/2018 17:22:50",
  "Size": "5 KB",
}, {
  "Name": "presets",
  "Type": "Directory",
  "DateModified": "5/11/2018 7:32:10",
  "Size": "2 KB",
}, {
  "Name": "workflow",
  "Type": "Directory",
  "DateModified": "6/26/2018 10:29:59",
  "Size": "6 KB",
}, {
  "Name": "software",
  "Type": "Directory",
  "DateModified": "3/16/2018 10:29:59",
  "Size": "16 KB",
}, {
  "Name": "mmm_data",
  "Type": "Directory",
  "DateModified": "6/27/2018 1:19:29",
  "Size": "3 KB",
}, {
  "Name": "jobs",
  "Type": "Directory",
  "DateModified": "4/27/2018 11:59:59",
  "Size": "3 KB",
}, ];
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <input type="text" id="autoSuggest" placeholder="Search..." onkeyup="changeInput(this.value)">
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: might give this a look: https://dev.to/stephenafamo/how-to-create-an-autocomplete-input-with-plain-javascript

Comment: There are so many pure JS autocomplete libraries. Why do you write it from scrap?

Comment: or check out good ol autoComplete: https://goodies.pixabay.com/javascript/auto-complete/demo.html

Comment: @organism.exe thanks I did read that one; but it is using a php data source

Comment: @No-Spex as it states, you can use and JSON-formatted data source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match on `file.Name`, and not `file`. The filter callback function should then return a `true/false` value and not the object

```js
var json = [{
  "Name": "zips",
  "Type": "Directory",
  "DateModified": "6/14/2018 17:22:50",
  "Size": "5 KB",
}, {
  "Name": "presets",
  "Type": "Directory",
  "DateModified": "5/11/2018 7:32:10",
  "Size": "2 KB",
}, {
  "Name": "workflow",
  "Type": "Directory",
  "DateModified": "6/26/2018 10:29:59",
  "Size": "6 KB",
}, {
  "Name": "software",
  "Type": "Directory",
  "DateModified": "3/16/2018 10:29:59",
  "Size": "16 KB",
}, {
  "Name": "mmm_data",
  "Type": "Directory",
  "DateModified": "6/27/2018 1:19:29",
  "Size": "3 KB",
}, {
  "Name": "jobs",
  "Type": "Directory",
  "DateModified": "4/27/2018 11:59:59",
  "Size": "3 KB",
}, ];




function matchIt(input) {
  var reg = new RegExp(input.split('').join('\\w*').replace(/\W/, ""), 'i');
  return json.filter(file => !!file.Name.match(reg));
}

function changeInput(val) {
  if (val.length == 0) return;
  var autoCompleteResult = matchIt(val);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = autoCompleteResult.map(i => i.Name).join('<br>')
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <input type="text" id="autoSuggest" placeholder="Search..." onkeyup="changeInput(this.value)">
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```